# Java program hangs at same random spot consistently

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory

I had to do a program that would generate 30 graphs in total, with 5 having 10 unique edges, 5 having 20 unique edges, etc up to 60. I then had to take the average amount of components across in each of the 5 graphs. However, my program is hanging consistently in the same spot. It is when it is trying to do the 16th graph and the 11th edge that it fails, all the time. I left out the connected components static method since that is irrelevant to the problem, I believe. Note this is a rough draft of an earlier optimized copy, both get hung at the same place.

First, I make one graph with the 26 vertices required and then put that same graph into each of the 30 spots in the array and then I put the unique edges into each graph.

The edgeIs method and the indexIs method are in the graph ADT I am using.

Here is the code:

```
import ch05.queues.LinkedUnbndQueue;
import ch05.queues.UnboundedQueueInterface;

import java.util.Random;

public class UniqueEdgeGraph2 {

public static void main (String[] args) {


    final int numGraphs2 = 5;
    int numEdges = 10;
    double sum = 0;
    int index = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum1 = 0, randomNum2 = 0, flag = 0;
    UnweightedGraph<Integer>[] graphArray = (UnweightedGraph<Integer>[]) new UnweightedGraph[30];

    UnweightedGraph<Integer> graph;

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
     graphArray[i] = new UnweightedGraph<Integer>();

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
           graphArray[i].addVertex(j);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // it is done 6 times because 30 graphs are needed in total and numGraphs is 5
        for (int j = 0; j < numGraphs2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < numEdges; k++) {
                while (flag == 0) {
                     randomNum1 = rand.nextInt(26);
                     randomNum2 = rand.nextInt(26);
                     if (graphArray[index].edgeIs(randomNum1, randomNum2) == false) {
                        graphArray[index].addEdge(randomNum1, randomNum2);
                        flag = 1;
                     }
                }   
                flag = 0;
            }
            sum += CountConnectedComponents(graphArray[index]);
            index++;
        }
            System.out.println("Average # of Connected Components for five graphs with " + numEdges + " unique edges is: "
                    + sum/5.0);
            sum = 0;
            numEdges += 10;

    }   
}

public boolean edgeIs(T fromVertex, T toVertex)
  // If edge from fromVertex to toVertex exists, returns true
  // otherwise, returns false.
  {
    int row;
    int column;

    row = indexIs(fromVertex);
    column = indexIs(toVertex);
    return (edges[row][column]);
  }

 private int indexIs(T vertex)
  // Returns the index of vertex in vertices.
  {
    int index = 0;
    while (!vertex.equals(vertices[index]))
      index++;
    return index;
  }
```

Comment: can you post up .edgeIs function as well?

Comment: do you mean `hang` or `endless loop`

Comment: I posted the edgeIs function. I mean hang, when I debug it, it just stops there for some reason. I have an earlier version where I would have the same, repeated loop for each of the 5 buckets of graphs with the same amount of unique edges and it would run fine for the first 3 loops before stalling.

Comment: what is this code `return (edges[row][column]);`  where is `edges` defined?  I guess this always returns false, or some exception is thrown which you are not telling us about.

Comment: Do this code even compile?

Comment: Edges is within the Graph ADT. It is a 2D boolean array to keep track of the edges. If there is an edge between two vertices, it gets marked as true. The vertices are in an array as well so if the two vertices given to the edgeIs method were in the 0 and 1 index of the vertex array, both edges[0][1] and edges[1][0] would get marked as true since it is an undirected graph.

Comment: It compiles but it is using the Graph ADT and the queue ADT that was given to me. You can comment out the queue and connectedcomponent sum part. If you want the graph ADT entirely, I can post it if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the error was. I was pointing to the same graph for all 30 array indices. So instead of making 30 different graphs, I pointed the entire array to one graph. This made it impossible to eventually find a unique edge to put in, which caused an infinite loop instead of it just hanging like I thought it was.

I edited the code to reflect the changes I made to make it work. It is still in rough shape but it just needs to be cleaned up.

Thanks to everybody who commented.